# SQL Error (1728): Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corruptedNotice:

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a dump database from online server to my localhost Mysql.
It imported some table than it shows this

> SQL Error (1728): Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corruptedNotice: You can disable the "Stop on errors in batch mode" option to ignore such errors

I am stuck here and not able to figure out what causes this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it any way to update the system database for mysql? 1728- Can not load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import the system database `mysql` as well as your intended database(s). From the explanation of what you are trying to do, it doesn't sound like this is what you want/need.

Comment: I am not trying to import system database and also i have seached in the dump file there is not any mysql.proc. This is dump from my live system application and has not to do with the system database.

Comment: Is it any way to update the system database for mysql?  1728- Can not load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted